# Npm offline package installation in docker container

Tags: docker, npm, npm-install, node-red, npm-package

I am trying to install node-red-contrib-influxdb in a node-red docker container that is on a computer with no way to access internet. I have a Windows computer, that I have also installed node.js on, and installed/downloaded the node-red-contrib-influxdb package and npm-pack-all.

I tried to run npm-pack-all in the node-red-contrib-influxdb install location to get all the dependencies installed (those dependencies I have installed manually as well, but this didn't help) and moved the resulting tgz file to the docker container and ran npm install on it. This results in a following error:

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/influx failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/node-red/.npm/_logs/2023-01-31T14_33_13_404Z-debug.log
```

With the relevant lines in the log being:

```
15 silly resolveWithNewModule node-red-contrib-influxdb@0.6.1 checking installable status
16 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for influx@5.6.3 request to https://registry.npmjs.org/influx failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
17 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 19ms
18 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 7103ms
19 silly saveTree node-red-project@0.0.1
19 silly saveTree +-- @influxdata/influxdb-client@1.33.1
19 silly saveTree +-- influx@5.9.3
19 silly saveTree +-- lodash@4.17.21
19 silly saveTree `-- node-red-contrib-influxdb@0.6.1
20 verbose type system
21 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/influx failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
21 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:68:14)
21 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
21 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
21 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
21 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
21 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
21 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
22 verbose cwd /data
23 verbose Linux 4.4.0-cip-rt-moxa-imx7d
24 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "./node-red-contrib-influxdb-0.6.1.tgz"
25 verbose node v14.18.2
26 verbose npm  v6.14.15
27 error code EAI_AGAIN
28 error errno EAI_AGAIN
29 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/influx failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
30 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

How would I resolve this error and enable offline installation of this particular npm package?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a different way.

Create a custom Node-RED container by extending the existing container and then install the required nodes while building the container (on a machine with internet access) then copy the new container to your offline machine.

e.g.

```
FROM nodered/node-red:latest
USER root
RUN npm install node-red-contrib-influxdb
USER node-red
```

The USER switch is because the install will be into `/usr/src/node-red` which is along side Node-RED

Comment: My problem is that I have internet connection on a windows machine, and need to deploy on a docker container on an offline linux machine. This is why I'd like to have a file to transfer the npm installation files manually rather than dealing with docker stuff. In addition, the linux is running on arm v7, so there is an architecture difference as well.

Comment: The problem with trying to bundle on the windows machine is that it will build any native components with the wrong arch/os and the docker container may also be missing required pre-requisite libraries. You really need a similar machine with network access.

Comment: It is near impossible to get the machine online, I've tried, but the current location/network options make that impossible.

Comment: I didn't stay get the machine online, I said "get a similar machine online"